# Parallel actions

Tags: grammar

Please look

> The Kremlin has turned a blind eye to these violations so long as
>   Kadyrov, a brutal and violent strongman, continues to fulfill his
>   mission on the Russian government’s behalf.

Does this mean the same as

> The Kremlin has turned a blind eye to these violations so long as
>   Kadyrov, a brutal and violent strongman, has continued  to fulfill his
>   mission on the Russian government’s behalf.

or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither is really correct.

The sentence describes activities that started in the past and are ongoing.  So you are correct about "continues", which refers only to the present.  It should be "has continued", as you suggested.

But "so long as" means "only if", as in, "I’ll lend you the money so long as you’ll pay me back." [*source.*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so-long-as)  It also generally refers to something that would happen in the future.

"As long as" would be the more appropriate phrase.  It can have a number of meanings, the relevant one being "during the time that". [*source.*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+long+as)